# Accidentally stored string instead of object in Postgres JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I just realized that the data being inserted into a JSONB column is a string like `"{\"foo\": 3}"` instead of an object like `{"foo": 3}`. I'm pretty sure the cause is due to setting the SQLAlchemy model's field with

```
reading.blob = blob_json
```

instead of

```
reading.blob = json.loads(blob_json)
```

I haven't been able to figure out a way to correct the existing data, though. The Postgres docs give examples of converting text to JSON, extracting array and object elements out of JSON, etc., but I can't find anything that shows how to select the text of a JSONB column that has only one string value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just when I got this:

```
SELECT (('"{\"foo\":42}"'::JSONB)->>0)::JSONB;
```

Answer (score 3):

Eureka! DeciBull on #postgres came up with

```
SELECT (json_build_array('"{\"Stuff.Hello\": 0, \"Stuff.Hello2\": 1000}"'::jsonb)->>0)::jsonb

{"Stuff.Hello": 0, "Stuff.Hello2": 1000}
```